# Polymer core-ajax element vs XHR

Tags: ajax, polymer

I'm starting out with Polymer and came across core-ajax element. I'd like to know what's the typical use case for it - why use the element and not normal XHR

What I don't really get is **why** it's an element. And now I'm thinking I'm missing some basic idea, ajax needs to be in the DOM because (..?..), or it's easier like this because (..?..)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For the most part it's just a matter of preference, a sort of [imperative vs declarative](http://latentflip.com/imperative-vs-declarative/) debate with no real "right" answer.

One of the great things about web components is the potential for encapsulation.  Normally, to get a decent cross-browser XHR you'd have to use a dedicated library of some sort, or use jQuery or a similar "kitchen sink" framework.

By using an ajax web component, you can easily build AJAX functionality right into one of your own components, or when including it on a page you can easily bind the XHR results to another element or component, sidestepping the usual `page ready -> execute XHR -> handle Promise -> output results` process, which can get tedious when multiple elements on the page use dynamically loaded data.

There's a few other benefits when using the [`iron-ajax`](https://elements.polymer-project.org/elements/iron-ajax) component, specifically. It has built-in request debouncing and a `loading` property that's handy for showing loading indicators on the page.  These aren't things dedicated libraries can't do, but when you're working with Polymer/web components a lot, you get pretty comfortable with dealing with elements with complex behaviors.